# How to allow trackpad use while bluetooth mouse is connected (MacOS Big Sur)?

Tags: macos, mouse, bluetooth

I can't figure out how to have both operational. It's frustrating when I take my computer into the other room and can't use my trackpad b/c my mouse is connected.

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/289022/how-to-disable-your-macs-touchpad-when-another-mouse-is-connected/

Comment: This was it. In Accessibility it is now 'Pointer'

Comment: It was literally the first, second and third result in a default search engine.

Comment: I think I saw that but when the Mouse option wasn't available I thought it was out-dated for my version.